# "Unwrap" not working in UV map

Tags: uv

Why can't I make my circle appear in the UV map, when I'm using "Unwrap" button?
I'm following some guide on YouTube, and I'm doing everything exactly as it is in guide.
First screenshot is from guide. Second one is my screen after I pressed "Unwrap" button.

[image: It should be like that, this screenshot is from guide]
[image: My screen after I pressed "Unwrap" on my circle]

Comment: Did you select All (A key) in Edit mode before unwrapping? You also have the viewport set to Material Preview mode rather than Solid mode so you wouldn't be able to see if everything was selected or not before you unwrapped the object.

Comment: I tried doing what you said and it didn't help :( But I've got an advise to try using hotkey  "u" instead for unwrapping. And it worked for some reason. But thank you so much anyway! <3

Comment: Using 'U' with the cursor in the 3D view is the normal way to unwrap an object so I'm not sure how you were doing it?

Comment: Right click + "unwrap" from UV context menu.
https://prnt.sc/PFcZ0b6Z34V7

Comment: Ah! No. I've never unwrapped using the UV editor Unwrap menu. The "normal" way is to use the one in the 3D view as you've now found.